# PHP based code for filtering mysql results, can I make this more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I've made this php code for filtering the results from a mysql database. It works very well, but I'm sure this is not the most efficient way (or proper use of the language) to achieve the desired results. I'm trying my best to get "good" at writing code and would appreciate some feedback on how I could do this better.

```
$filter = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$aircraft_reg = "";
$prefix = "";
$part_number = "";
$flight_control = "";

if(!empty($_POST['aircraft_reg']))
    {
    $aircraft_reg = "aircraft_reg = '" . $_POST['aircraft_reg'] . "'";
    }
if(!empty($_POST['prefix']))
    {
    $prefix = "prefix = '" . $_POST['prefix'] . "'";
    }
if(!empty($_POST['part_number']))
    {
    $part_number = "part_number = '" . $_POST['part_number'] . "'";
    }
if(!empty($_POST['flight_control']))
    {
    $flight_control = "flight_control = '" . $_POST['flight_control'] . "'";
    }   
if ($aircraft_reg != "" && ($prefix != "" || $part_number != "" || $flight_control != ""))
    {
    $a = " AND ";
    }
else
    {
    $a = "";
    }
if ($prefix != "" && ($part_number != "" || $flight_control != ""))
    {
    $b = " AND ";
    }
else
    {
    $b = "";
    }
if ($part_number != "" && $flight_control != "")
    {
    $c = " AND ";
    }
else
    {
    $c = "";
    }
if ($aircraft_reg != "" || $prefix != "" || $part_number != "" || $flight_control != "")
    {
    $filter = "WHERE " . $aircraft_reg . $a . $prefix . $b . $part_number . $c . $flight_control;
    }
}

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM installed $filter ORDER BY aircraft_reg , part_number, date_installed ASC");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need follow this pattern:

```
$result = mysql_query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM installed 
        WHERE  
            ".($_POST['aircraft_reg']?"aircraft_reg=" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aircraft_reg']):"1" )." AND     
            ...
        ORDER BY aircraft_reg , part_number, date_installed ASC");
```

another alternative:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    if($key!="submit" and $val)
        $filters[] = "$key='".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."' ";


$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM installed 
    ".(isset($filters)?"WHERE ".implode("AND ",$filters):"")."      
    ORDER BY aircraft_reg , part_number, date_installed ASC");
```

Comment: Putting `$_POST` values directly in a query is a Bad Idea. *Always* escape them or suffer SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Specifying field names instead of just * will make your query bit faster!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using something well-established such as ActiveRecord:

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

No need to re-invent the wheel (unless this is purely for learning, in which case, carry on!)

... in the case this is purely for learning, don't forget to escape any REQUEST data such as those $_POSTs that you're using, with something like mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: And that's how you learn ;-). I haven't heard of it, but have implemented my own version after being tired of creating the umpteenth SQL query.

Comment: Yes, I also wrote something very similar to ActiveRecord, but the advantages of using a well-established design pattern / library are pretty massive. Although I certainly learnt a thing or two, from a productivity standpoint it makes sense to just use ActiveRecord directly

Answer (score 0):

Quick:

1. Use array_key_exists to see if something is in `$_POST`
2. Do not put `$_POST` values directly in your SQL, escape them. More info when you Google for `SQL injection attack`
3. I would validate/sanitize your input first, and then create the query in one go:

   ```
   if (array_key_exists("partnumber", $_POST) {
        $part_number = validate_partnumber($_POST['partnumber']);
        $part_number = escape_for_db($part_number);
   }
   $q = ".... WHERE part_number='$part_number' ....";
   ```

Other than that, it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: If this is for anything serious though he should really just use ActiveRecord or a similar pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, as conditional operator has less time complexity than `if()-else()`. Moreover less use of variables will cause less memory allocation, hence it is faster and more optimized than the one you used.
Another thing, using `mysql_real_escape_string()` prevent sql injection.

```
$filter = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $condition_count = 0;

    if(!empty($_POST['aircraft_reg']))
    {
        $filter = " WHERE aircraft_reg = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aircraft_reg']) . "'";
        $condition_count++;
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['prefix']))
    {
        $condition_count > 0?$filter .= " AND prefix = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix']) . "'":$filter .= " WHERE prefix = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix']) . "'";
        $condition_count++;
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['part_number']))
    {
        $condition_count > 0?$filter .= " AND part_number = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_number']) . "'":$filter .= " WHERE part_number = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_number']) . "'";
        $condition_count++;
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['flight_control']))
    {
        $condition_count > 0?$filter .= " AND flight_control = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['flight_control']) . "'":$filter .= " WHERE flight_control = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['flight_control']) . "'";
        $condition_count++;
    }
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM installed ".$filter." ORDER BY aircraft_reg , part_number, date_installed ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) exit;

$aircraft_reg = $_POST['aircraft_reg'];
$prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
$part_number = $_POST['part_number'];
$flight_control = $_POST['flight_control'];

$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM installed 
    where 
        aircraft_reg = if('$aircraft_reg' = '', aircraft_reg, '$aircraft_reg')
        and
        prefix = if('$prefix' = '', prefix, '$prefix')
        and
        part_number = if('$part_number' = '', part_number, '$part_number')
        and
        flight_control = if('$flight_control' = '', flight_control, '$flight_control')
    ORDER BY aircraft_reg , part_number, date_installed
    ");
```

If this is for real then don't forget to sanitize the user input or you will be an easy sql injection victim.